# Struts 1.3 customized validwhen validator

Tags: validation, struts

I have a form in struts 1.3 which is dynamically generated one and having indexed properties.
I want to validate that form with struts validation framework.

Here is my situation:
there is a field called page which should be even number certain personnames. For this I have to create customize valid when in struts. Do u guys have any idea?

```
<field property="page" indexedListProperty="data"
    depends="validwhenpage,integer,intRange">
  <arg0 key="err.personname.page.valid"/>
  <var>
      <var-name>test</var-name>
      <var-value>((data[].personname=='ramesh') or (*this* ????))</var-value>         
  </var>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can create Action Error object and save the error message in our action class and we can do the validation what ever we want

```
errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("test","test1");
            saveErrors(request, errors);
```